# AND query in Elasticsearch

Tags: json, search, indexing, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm trying to filter my query by 2 fields, but keep getting error. I'm using the AND query as suggested by Elasticsearch docs (it's actually a 'bool' query), here-
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html

```
GET /index_v1/user/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        { "term": { "id": "101"   }},
        { "term": { "firstName": "John"   }}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works-

```
    GET /index_v1/user/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
          "match": {
              "id": "101"               
           }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and returns this-

```
    {
   "took": 24,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 3.442347,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "index_v1",
            "_type": "user",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 3.442347,
            "_source": {
               "id": "101",
               "firstName": "John",
               "guid": "1001",
               "lastName": "Doe",
               "email": "john.doe@company.com",
               "entitlements": {
                  "id": "en2"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "index_v1",
            "_type": "user",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 3.140066,
            "_source": {
               "id": "101",
               "firstName": "John",
               "guid": "1001",
               "lastName": "Doe",
               "email": "john.doe@company.com",
               "tenants": [
                  {
                     "id": "12345",
                     "roles": [
                        "PrimaryAdmin"
                     ]
                  }
               ],
               "entitlements": {
                  "id": "en2"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's the mapping document-

```
{
   "index_v1": {
      "mappings": {
         "user": {
            "properties": {
               "email": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "entitlements": {
                  "properties": {
                     "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "firstName": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "guid": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "id": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "lastName": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "tenants": {
                  "properties": {
                     "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "roles": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Also, how can I add this to AND condition

```
["tenants"]["id"]="12345"
```

Comment: please post the mappings of your index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run a filtered query to use filters.  The relevant example you'll want is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-and-query.html).

```
GET /index_v1/user/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          { "term": { "id": "101" }},
          { "term": { "firstName": "John" }},
          { "term": { "tenants.id": "12345" }}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That should be roughly it, though I'm sure you'll have to tweak it (I'm a little rusty).

In order for the id fields to match exactly, you'll want to set those fields to be analyzed as keywords in the mapping, otherwise ES will try to get smart with it and give you unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks Nick, that sounded promising, but I got the same- "SearchPhaseExecutionException: SearchParseException"

Comment: @Maryam I've updated the post to include a link to the relevant example in the ES docs.  If you could, please post the full error dump you get back and it will help us clear this up quickly.

Comment: there is a comma missing after query clause.

Answer (score 0):

The query posted by Nick Larson should work fine, but as far as exactly what is wrong with your query, you are using *curly* brackets where you should be using *square* brackets (it's actually invalid JSON syntax, in it's current form).  `"filter"` should be an array, so you have to use square brackets:

```
GET /index_v1/user/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": { "id": "101"   }},
        { "term": { "firstName": "John"   }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```